# Active faces of the object and UV unwrap not corresponding

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv

I UV unwrapped a cylindrical object but noticed that the image was stretched with a section of the image missing. The active face of the image and the corresponding active face shown in the UV Image Editor window show different contents as such . Why is this happening? I have managed to cheat as shown below. [image][image]